# Preferred way of structuring Redish hash store

Tags: redis

I have a number of objects; each object belongs to one or more categories. For each object, I have a serialized string representing the properties of the relevant object-category pair.

I would like to set up a store to retrieve those properties, knowing the category id and object id. I could set up the store in the following ways:

**1: Fewer keys, more fields per key**

- Have a hash `category:{category_id}` that, for each key, stores a value that has field names `object_id` and field values set to that object-category pair's json-stringified properties.

**2: More keys, one field per key**

- Have a hash `category-object:{category_id}-{object_id}` that, for each key, stores a single field equal to that category-object pair's json-stringified properties.

I would like to compare the two approaches' performance properties, but I cannot find any meaningful differences. Are there any  advantages of one approach over the other?

*Note the value storage is a given - the value stored need to be json-stringified properties.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should expect a slightly better performance using one key (`category-object:{category_id}-{object_id}`) using `SET` and `GET` commands, than a hash with key name `category:{category_id}` and field name `{object_id}` using `HSET` and `HGET` commands.

Both `GET` and `HGET` are time complexity O(1). The first one (`GET`) will run the hashing function once on the key name and then look up once on the hash map. The second one (`HGET`) will do the same twice. Hence a slight difference.

But this difference, next to the Round Trip Time, is negligible and I wouldn't use it as criteria for the design decision.

Instead, other criteria would be:

- Would I ever need to get all objects for a given category? Then use the first approach, as one command will get you that (`HGETALL`) whereas in the second approach you would need to `SCAN` and then `GET`.
- Would I ever need to `EXPIRE` a given `{category_id}-{object_id}`? This would imply the second approach because you cannot expire a field of a hash.
- Would I ever need to get all the `{category_id}-{object_id}` values for a given object? This may tilt the balance for the second approach because there I only need to `SCAN`. IN the first approach I would need to `SCAN` then `HSCAN` on each result.

If you want to run some actual benchmarks, see [How fast is Redis?](https://redis.io/topics/benchmarks)